# Error en php con consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

no sé hacer esta pregunta muy larga ya que no sé por qué esta consulta no me funciona. Según el archivo en *localhost* me da error de encapsulamiento pero no le veo el error si alquien me ayuda lo agradezco :

```
mysqli_query($conexion'
INSERT INTO sr_escalas 
(nombre, nombre_esp, nombre_eng, nombre_bra, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, orden) VALUES 
(\'Escala Nº 1\', \'Escala Nº 1\', \'Escala Nº 1\', \'Escala Nº 1\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 2\', \'Escala Nº 2\', \'Escala Nº 2\', \'Escala Nº 2\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 3\', \'Escala Nº 3\', \'Escala Nº 3\', \'Escala Nº 3\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 4\', \'Escala Nº 4\', \'Escala Nº 4\', \'Escala Nº 4\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 5\', \'Escala Nº 5\', \'Escala Nº 5\', \'Escala Nº 5\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 6\', \'Escala Nº 6\', \'Escala Nº 6\', \'Escala Nº 6\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 7\', \'Escala Nº 7\', \'Escala Nº 7\', \'Escala Nº 7\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 8\', \'Escala Nº 8\', \'Escala Nº 8\', \'Escala Nº 8\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 9\', \'Escala Nº 9\', \'Escala Nº 9\', \'Escala Nº 9\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0);
');
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

Comment: @lazarok ¿qué aporta [tu edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26865)? Creo que por dos puntitos no merece la pena añadir cursivas y negritas. Mejor céntrate en cambios importantes en la publicación para hacerlo mejor, no para hacerle photoshop ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya vi mi error yo mismo Gracias por sus intenciones era una simple Coma después de la palabra conexión, la manera correcta era esta:

```
mysqli_query($conexion,'
INSERT INTO sr_escalas 
(nombre, nombre_esp, nombre_eng, nombre_bra, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, orden) VALUES 
(\'Escala Nº 1\', \'Escala Nº 1\', \'Escala Nº 1\', \'Escala Nº 1\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 2\', \'Escala Nº 2\', \'Escala Nº 2\', \'Escala Nº 2\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 3\', \'Escala Nº 3\', \'Escala Nº 3\', \'Escala Nº 3\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 4\', \'Escala Nº 4\', \'Escala Nº 4\', \'Escala Nº 4\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 5\', \'Escala Nº 5\', \'Escala Nº 5\', \'Escala Nº 5\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 6\', \'Escala Nº 6\', \'Escala Nº 6\', \'Escala Nº 6\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 7\', \'Escala Nº 7\', \'Escala Nº 7\', \'Escala Nº 7\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 8\', \'Escala Nº 8\', \'Escala Nº 8\', \'Escala Nº 8\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0),
(\'Escala Nº 9\', \'Escala Nº 9\', \'Escala Nº 9\', \'Escala Nº 9\',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),\'%y-%m-%d\'), DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL \'.$Dias.\' DAY,\'%y-%m-%d\'), 0);
');
```